# why can't I create directories in virtual box shared folder? Windows 7 host, arch linux guest

Tags: linux, virtualbox, shared-folders

I'm mounting a shared folder in an arch linux guest on a windows 7 host in Virtual Box. The shared folder's filesystem is ext3 and is mounted in windows 7 with Ext2Fsd.

I mount the shared folder at boot with this fstab:

```
D_DRIVE /home/tony vboxsf rw,gid=1000,uid=1000,auto 0 0
```

I believe my user in the guest OS has the right uid and gid:

```
[tony@kiwi ~]$ id
uid=1000(tony) gid=1000(tony) groups=1000(tony),1002,(vboxsf)
```

I can create files and remove them fine, but I can't seem to create directories.

```
[tony@kiwi ~]$ mkdir foo
mkdir: cannot create directory `foo': Protocol error
```

Its weird because the directory looks like its there, sort of.

```
[tony@kiwi ~]$ ls -lh
ls: cannot access foo: No such file or directory
total 0
????????? ? ?     ?     ?                ? foo
```

The same thing happens with the root user. I can't create symlinks either. Again, creating and deleting normal files seems to work fine.

So anyone have any ideas?

Also, if anyone has any alternative suggestions to shared folders I'd be happy to hear about it. I was going to use an NTFS folder as a share, but I'd like to be able to have symlinks.

Comment: Have you tried sharing the folder without going through vbox shared folders? When the guest & host are both running, you can use whatever network file sharing you desire. I think that vbox shared folders adds an additional layer of abstraction that may be the cause of your problem.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking of doing, I'm not sure what network file sharing protocol I should use. Samba? SSHfs? nfs?

Comment: Ill just try samba.

Comment: Samba is much nicer.... :\

Comment: So you got it working?

Comment: I'm having some other issues with samba that I'll have to make new questions for, but yes. :)

Comment: Could you not simply mount it as ext instead of vboxfs? In any case, if you solved it, why not post your answer so we can have one fewer unanswered question :) ?

Comment: My solution was to use samba instead, which I posted as an answer, and was deleted. Not sure why it was deleted. :\